# Which collection should I use (key - value)?

Tags: java, android

In my application i have the class:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private float calories;
    ...
}
```

In addition, I have a list of products that has been added to the meal, e.g. to Breakfast. I save these products in ArrayList.

```
abstract class Meal {

protected float amountCalories;
protected float amountFat;
protected float amountCarbohydrates;
protected float amountProtein;

protected List<Product> listOfProduct = new ArrayList<Product>(); // previously mentioned product list
...   

}
```

Next, I need a key - value mechanism, where the key will be the date of the meal 
while the value of the product list. Which collection will be the most suitable and give me good 
efficiency? Will it be HashMap or something else?

Comment: When you said "key will be the date of the meal", is it with the time as well or just the date portion? Because if you use only the date portion, you can only add one meal per day.

Comment: And based on what you have mentioned a HashMap will be suitable. But if you are intended to use this in a multi-threaded environment, you may have to consider a Concurrent HashMap (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: The key will be only part of the date without time, I am aware that I will be able to add only one meal, because the key must be unique (from what I remember). That's why I created the abstract Meal class, which they will inherit, other classes like: breakfast, lunch etc. So every meal will have its own ArrayList and HashMap. I just don't know if HashMap is the collection I need.

Comment: So are you going to define this HashMap (or whatever the Key-Value data structure) inside your `Meal` class?

Comment: Of course, ArrayList will be in the Meal abstract class so that each meal has its own list of products. However, the HashMap data structure will not be in the inside of the Meal class because it seems pointless to me.

Comment: Yes, I also thought it was pointless. But since you said "every meal will have its own ArrayList and HashMap", I wanted to verify if I understood you correctly

Answer (score 3):

I guess you only use the date, otherwise, if it's a date / time, it will be more efficient to use it as a property in the Meal class.

To be able to have many Meals with the same key use:

```
Map<Date, List<Meal>>
```

You can use either `TreeMap` or `HashMap`. Both implementations form an integral part of the Java Collections Framework and store data as key-value pairs.

- A HashMap works on the principle of [hashing](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode) and usually acts as a bucketed hash table, but when buckets get too large, they get transformed into nodes of TreeNodes, each structured similarly to those in java.util.TreeMap.
- TreeMap extends AbstractMap class and implements NavigableMap interface. A TreeMap stores map elements in a Red-Black tree, which is a **Self-Balancing Binary Search Tree**.

**Performance HashMap**

HashMap, being a hashtable-based implementation, internally uses an array-based data structure to organize its elements according to the hash function.

HashMap provides expected constant-time performance O(1) for most operations like add(), remove() and contains(). Therefore, it's significantly faster than a TreeMap.

The average time to search for an element under the reasonable assumption, in a hash table is O(1). But, an improper implementation of the hash function may lead to a poor distribution of values in buckets which results in:

- Memory Overhead – many buckets remain unused
- Performance Degradation – the higher the number of collisions, the lower the performance

**Performance TreeMap**

A TreeMap stores its data in a hierarchical tree with the ability to sort the elements with the help of a custom Comparator.

A summary of its performance:

- TreeMap provides a performance of O(log(n)) for most operations like add(), remove() and contains()
- A Treemap can save memory (in comparison to HashMap) because it only uses the amount of memory needed to hold its items, unlike a HashMap which uses contiguous region of memory
- A tree should maintain its balance in order to keep its intended performance, this requires a considerable amount of effort, hence complicates the implementation

We should go for a TreeMap whenever:

- memory limitations have to be taken into consideration
- we don't know how many items have to be stored in memory
- we want to extract objects in a natural order
- if items will be consistently added and removed
- we're willing to accept O(log n) search time

> See more: https://www.baeldung.com/java-treemap-vs-hashmap